# Laravel 4 PHP Fatal error: Class 'Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter' not found in bootstrap/compiled.php on line 7991

Tags: laravel-4, monolog

I haven't used composer or Laravel 4 during the last couple of weeks, today I created a new Laravel project and suddenly Monolog is causing a ton of problems.

At first I was unable to fully create the project, afterwards I was unable to create a migration, and now I can't run php artisan serve any more. I followed the steps on [Laravel 4 Class not found in bootstrap/compiled.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20732169/laravel-4-class-not-found-in-bootstrap-compiled-php) and that helped the first time around, but after creating the second migration and wanting to run a php artisan migrate I get the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter' not found in /bootstrap/compiled.php on line 7991
```

How do I fix this?

I have update composer using self-update, I have tried to use dump-autoload, and the other steps in the question I posted a link to.

Comment: Your Laravel installation may be broken, try reinstalling it.

Comment: First time I got this error was right after creating a new project, prior to creating the project I ran a composer self-update. This is a very fresh installation. I saw something about Monolog using a newer version of PSR.

Comment: I'm getting this to. It cannot be a corrupt laravel installation, as it is happening when I try to do a fresh installation. Did you get any where with this?

Comment: I just tried with a new composer/composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist as described in the Laravel documentation, still getting same error Error Output: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter'

Comment: Did you tried `composer dump-autoload`.

Comment: Have you actually ran composer install? Could do with more detail on how you have installed Laravel.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by deleting the `vendor`folder and then running a `composer install` to ensure a fresh install of all packages in the composer.json.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you installed the project. If you're trying to impose Laravel 4 over an old project, I suggest you to install FRESH Laravel using this command

composer create-project laravel/laravel project_name --prefer-dist

This should not give you any installation related problem unless the Laravel installation itself is broken. Which is very unlikely to happen.

You can then copy your controllers, models, migrations etc from the old project.

Good luck.